# Load JSON file in Sigma.js but can't bind overEdge Event

Tags: javascript, json, graph, dom-events, sigma.js

I want to load some data from a JSON file and graph them in Sigma.js, and bind overEdge and outEdge event with all edges. I read some examples in official document and solved the problem when I want to bind overNode event in my code, but the the same way using to bind overEdge event doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
<script>

sigma.parsers.json(
    '../data/data.json', 
    {
        container: 'graph-container',
        type: 'canvas',
        settings: {
            defaultNodeColor: '#ec5148',
            enableEdgeHovering: true,
            edgeHoverColor: 'edge',
            defaultEdgeHoverColor: '#000',
            edgeHoverSizeRatio: 1,
            edgeHoverExtremities: true,
        }
    },
    function(s) {         
        s.graph.nodes().forEach(function(n) {
            s.bind('overNode', 
                function(e) {
                    alert("node");
                }
            );  
        });

        s.graph.edges().forEach(function(n) {
            s.bind('overEdge', 
                function(e) {
                    alert('edge');                                          
                }
            );
        });
    }
);

</script>
```

When I run my code, it seems that

```
enableEdgeHovering: true,
```

made some mistake like

> Uncaught Error: The edge events feature is not compatible with the WebGL renderer

but when I delete that, my edge can not bind events. I see official example do the same, and their code can work on my browser, but my code can't.

Answer (score 0):

May it isn't actually for you. This is working example from my project:

```
  <div id="container">
  <style>
    #graph-container {
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      position: absolute;
    }
  </style>
  <div id="graph-container"></div>
</div>
<script>
  s = new sigma({
    graph: 0,
    container: 'graph-container',
      renderer: {
        container: document.getElementById('graph-container'),
        type: 'canvas'
      },
      settings: {
            doubleClickEnabled: false,
            minEdgeSize: 0.5,
            maxEdgeSize: 4,
            enableEdgeHovering: true,
            edgeHoverColor: '#000',
            defaultEdgeHoverColor: 'red',
            edgeHoverSizeRatio: 1,
            edgeHoverExtremities: true,
            defaultEdgeLabelSize: 20,
            edgeLabelSize: 'proportional',
            minArrowSize: 10,
      }
  });
  sigma.parsers.json('data/arctic.json', s);
  s.bind('overNode outNode clickNode doubleClickNode rightClickNode', function(e) {
    console.log(e.type, e.data.node.label, e.data.captor);
  });
</script>
```